# How get id from dynamic button ? (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I use `jQuery` & `PDO` to dynamic a pagination

When I create some `button` which have `id = xx`

Then use jQuery try get one of `button` id , It isn't work

This is my code:

```
$records    = $databaseConnection->query("SELECT * FROM area ORDER BY FIELD(local,'Earth','Mars','Mercury','Sun')LIMIT $start, $records_per_page");
$count      = $records->rowCount();
$HTML='<table border="1"><tr><th>local</th><th>target</th><th>detail</th></tr>';
if($count > 0)
{
    foreach($records as $row) {
        $HTML.='<tr>';
        $HTML.='<td>'.$row['local'].'</td>';
        $HTML.='<td>'.$row['target'].'</td>';
        $HTML.='<td><button class = click id ='.$row['id']. '>detail</button></td>';
        $HTML.='</tr>';

    }
$HTML.='</table>';
}

else
{
    $HTML='No Data Found';
}
echo $HTML;
echo $pagination;
```

This is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    alert(this.id);
  });
});
```

If I code :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Planet </title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="library/jQuery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("button").click(function(){
                    alert(this.id);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    (dynamic of pagination code)
    ...
    ...
    ...

    <button id = "1"> try </button>
    </body>
</html>
```

when I click the `button` which `id = 1` ,It is work

But dynamic button isn't working...

What worng in my code ??

Comment: have to use `$(document).on("click","button",function(){ //do })`

Comment: I need take the time to read `on()` event...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to bind click handler using `.on()` for dynamically created elements, see below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on("click","button",function(){
    alert(this.id);
  });
});
```

**[More Information - .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

Comment: Shouldn't be "alert($(this).attr('id'));"?

Comment: Normal `.click()` handler can attach to already existing element in the page, but for dynamically created elements we need to attach click handler to `document` object and then delegate its call to `button` element. `.on()` delegates the  event to matched selector when click on page. Go through the more information link i have provided.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I just saw that you talking about dynamic added buttons.
I'm quite sure that delegated event handlers would help: http://api.jquery.com/on/

**Explanation of your problem:**

As you append your html dynamically, the newly created DOM objects don't have the event handlers attached because the code that attaches the handler **has already run.**

With **delegated event handlers**, you attach your event handlers to the parent element that **exists at the time we run the code** (it's document in this case). When the child elements are clicked (no event handlers), the event is bubbled up by browser and is handled by its parent (with event handlers attached)

Example

```
$(document).on('click',".close_fast",function(event){
     alert("hi");
 });
```

Comment: let me try put it this way :
My original code isn't handled dynamic code  that  create button can't be get, rigth ~?

Answer (score 0):

Your code says:

```
$HTML.='<td><button class = click id ='.$row['id']. '>詳情</button></td>';
```

Shouldn't that be:

```
$HTML.='<td><button class="click" id="'.$row['id']. '">詳情</button></td>';
```

Otherwise the HTML is invalid.

Comment: OK ，I modify this mistake , very appreciation !!